# Unclear on counting problem regarding ordering of sticks

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

Could someone please explain how there are *b* - 1 indistinguishable sticks in a row? And it looks like the expression is equivalent to the permutation P(*b*+*n*-1, *n*), but I am not sure how that even makes sense?

Comment: Are you familiar with [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))?

Comment: Thank you for suggesting that! The textbook I am using does not appear to mention that method at all. After studying it independently, seems like it would make intuitive sense that it really is indeed just the permutation P(b+n-1, n) (since "star" order is now important). If someone has a more precise explanation as to how or why that works (if my logic is sound), I would love to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

If you lay $b-1$ sticks in a row, you can think of the $b$ gaps formed between each pair of adjacent sticks (including two additional "gaps" on the ends) as the $b$ bins. Placing balls between two neighboring sticks represents putting balls in a bin.